# Insert picture with if statement based on aspect ratio (width/length >1 or <1)

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a macro, which works well. This will load pictures into colored merged cells from cell value location. The picture size will be the merged cell size (normally these are landscape orientated cells).

```
Sub INSERTPICTURES()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
With ws
    Dim cella As Range

    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("L2") & "\2_handover\CONDITION_SURVEY_REPORT\SURVEY_REPORT_" & Range("L2") & ".xlsm")

    For Each cella In .Range("a1:i60").Cells

        If cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 Then

        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=cella, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cella.MergeArea.Left, Top:=cella.MergeArea.Top, Width:=cella.MergeArea.Width, Height:=cella.MergeArea.Height)
        'cella.UnMerge
        shp.Name = cella.Value

        'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cella, cella.Value
        On Error Resume Next

        End If
    Next cella
End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Is there any way to build an if statement which will check the aspect ratio of the original picture (width/length)? And if it is greater than 1 or width pixel size is greater than length pixel size then insert with the above parameters (so `cella.MergeArea.theparameters`), and if the ratio is smaller then 1 (so the picture is a portrait orientation) I set up the top, left, width, length parameters with fix values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, insert the picture with its default width and height, and then check its aspect ratio, etc.  Also, you'll need to correct the error handling.  Try the following...

**EDIT**:  Note that the code has been amended so that for each cell in A1:I60, it first checks for an error, then it checks for a blank cell, then it checks the colorindex, and then checks to make sure that the path and filename is valid.  If so, it inserts the image.  Otherwise, a message pops up saying that the file is not found, along with the path and filename it couldn't find.  You can remove the message box, once you've finished testing.

```
Sub INSERTPICTURES()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            Dim cella As Range
            'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("L2") & "\2_handover\CONDITION_SURVEY_REPORT\SURVEY_REPORT_" & Range("L2") & ".xlsm")
            For Each cella In .Range("a1:i60").Cells
                If Not IsError(cella) Then
                    If Len(cella) > 0 Then
                        If cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 Then
                            If FileExists(cella.Value) Then
                                Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=cella, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cella.MergeArea.Left, Top:=cella.MergeArea.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1) 'default width and height
                                With shp
                                    .Name = cella.Value
                                    If .Width > .Height Then
                                        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                                        .Width = cella.MergeArea.Width
                                        .Height = cella.MergeArea.Height
                                    Else
                                        'set .LockAspectRatio to msoFalse
                                        'set width to fixed value
                                        'set height to fixed value
                                    End If
                                End With
                                'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cella, cella.Value
                            Else
                                MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & cella.Value, vbExclamation
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next cella
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub

Public Function FileExists(ByVal sFullname As String) As Boolean

    'returns True if file exists, otherwise it returns False
    'sFullname must contain both the path and filename (ie. c:\users\domenic\documents\sample.jpg)

    Dim fso As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    FileExists = fso.FileExists(sFullname)

    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you should either remove the error handler completely or limit it to the statement that really might fail - which is the `AddPicture`-statement (eg file not found). In that case, check if anything was assigned to `shp `.

Comment: @FunThomas Actually, that's an excellent suggestion.  I've edited my post to limit it  to the statement.  Thanks!

Comment: the code runs without error, however it is not loading any picture. The original one with cell value as path still loads them. I assume if the path points to landscape pictures the true part of the if statement should work the same way as my provided code. Or maybe it is not loading because the Nothing part is true?

Comment: Try temporarily commenting out or removing `On Error Resume Next`, and running it again.  Do you get an error?  If so, on which line does the error occur, and what type of error is it?

Comment: It says, cannot find the path specified, however the original macro works with no issue.

Comment: Try running it again without `On Error Resume Next`, but this time when the error occurs, click on Debug.  This should highlight the `ws.Shapes.AddPicture` line.  Then, move your cursor over the variable  `cella`.  What value has been assigned to it?  Is it a valid path and filename?

Comment: The variable is empty, nothing pops up.

Comment: Is there anything I can check?

Comment: It looks like you have one or more blank cells.  So I've amended the code to check for a blank cell, in addition to the colorindex.  If a cell isn't blank, and the colorindex is 48, but a picture still doesn't appear, check that the path and filename is correct and that the picture actually exists at that location.

Comment: If I swap the order of the "if len" and "if colorindex", then there is no error, however still not loading anything. I calculate the path in the cell value, some of the are not valid, my original macro going through them by clicking OK. I've tried also to remove all the invalid paths but not giving any results.

Comment: Thank you for your constant help, the macro itself still generating runtime error 13 type mismatch because of this row: If Len(Dir(cella.Value, vbNormal)) > 0 Then, cella.Value = Empty. I've deleted manually all the cells and kept 2 cells with color 48 and valid link in it. Still fail with this error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  We still need to check for a blank cell.  I've amended the code accordingly.  Does this help?

Comment: It runs on runtime error 1004: Application defined or object defined error, probably because of the invalid paths, however when I leave only the valid links (2) and colors, I can see the macro trying to download the two pictures, so the path is ok, but no picture appears in the cells. I also added the same statement to the else part, but still no picture was loaded.

Comment: With regards to checking for a valid path and filename, I've amended the code so that it uses another method.  I've included the function FileExists, which is called and passed the path and filename (ie. c:\users\domenic\documents\sample.jpg) in order to check.

Comment: The code runs without error and pops up all the invalid paths, however there is nothing loaded to the cells which are contain valid paths. I don't understand, the shape insert method is the same as my original code provided..

Comment: Try stepping through your code using the F8 key.  Then, when you reach the line `Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(...)` and try executing it, what happens?  Does the image get added to the worksheet?

Comment: Your code works, I've changed the picture paths pointing to local drive files instead of network files and it works. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: I've tested again, first I thought the network path is the issue but not. It looks like bigger sized pictures (like 3-4 mb) are not loaded into excel (the original macro loading them for some reason). So after resizing the pictures it works fine.

Comment: update: it loads the pictures however the else part is not working because the macro use the cella.MergeArea.Width and height in all cases, doesn't matter what is in the else

Comment: I had not problem with adding a 4 MB image, so the issue probably has to do with accessing it through a network.

Comment: Did you confirm that you in fact had one or more images whose height is greater than its width?

Comment: For the test I've two pictures: one landscape, on portrait. The landscape should go to cell1 (path pointing to the landscape picture) with cell1.width and cell1.height. In the cell2 the (path pointing to the portrait picture) should go with lockaspectratio=true and cell2.height is the height (I assume the width automatically comes) as the else statement because this picture height is greater than the width. But instead of doing this the portrait picture will be loaded in the same size as the landscape.

Comment: * will be loaded in the same size (cell1 size) as the landscape, but rotated in 90 degree.

Comment: In that case, check the orientation (ie. If shp.Rotation = 90 Then), and then adjust accordingly.